# Close old intent on notification click

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I having problem lunching new intent from local notification and closing the old one

Normally i start the intent with unique "key"

```
Intent queueIntent = new Intent(this, QueueListViewActivity.class);
queueIntent.putExtra("key","unique");
startActivity(queueIntent);
```

when i lunch the notification intent, it does not close the old one

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, QueueListViewActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("key", "myqueue");
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

how can i make the notification close the old intent if exist ?

Comment: How exactly would one "close" an Intent?

Comment: I tried to use android:launchMode="singleTop"
 on manifest but it's just close the old intent but doesnt start the new one

Comment: You should set your Activities to `android:launchMode=singleTask` in the manifest.  This will prevent duplicate Activities.

Comment: Read comment above you .. there is anyway to close old intent and start the new one ? with diffrent "putExtra("key", "myqueue")" >?

Comment: I think you're confusing `Intent` with `Activity`.

Comment: "public class QueueListViewActivity extends Activity", yes it's extend to activity